# I was writing some code and this error came up

Tags: c++, visual-c++

There are 2 errors expression must be a modifiable lvalue (line 12) and expected a statement (line 25). I am new to c++ and i only know scratch and qbasic. I have been sitting in front of this error for almost 2 hours now.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int d;
        cout << "Do you want Addition or Subtraction? (a/s)";
        cin >> d;

        if ('d' = "s");
    {
        int a, b;
        cout << "Enter any number: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Enter another number: ";
        cin >> b;
        int c = a + b;
        cout << "The sum is ";
        cout << c;

        return 1;

    }else{
        int e, f;
        cout << "Enter any number: ";
        cin >> e;
        cout << "Enter another number: ";
        cin >> f;
        int g = e + f;
        cout << "The sum is ";
        cout << g;

        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Use descriptive variable names (and function names when you get there). Good names make code easier to read because they give information about what a variable contains and how it should be used. The immediate benefit is it reduces the amount of commenting your code requires. In addition, the human brain has a really annoying habit of seeing the expected letter when the fingers typed in the wrong one. With a whole word if you screw up one character, the compiler usually catches the mistake. With a single character you can spend hours looking for the `i`-> `j` mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
   if ('d' = "s");
      {
```

to

```
 if (d == 's')
  {
```

This fixes 4 problems in your code

1. the variable name is `d` & not `'d'` (remove the single quotes around d in the if check. `d` is the variable `int d`. `'d'` is the character `d`.
2. Conditional Check should be `==` & not `=`. `=` is assignment. `==` is conditional check. This is the cause for the l-value error (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155665/what-are-the-key-terms-rvalue-and-lvalue)
3. The RHS of the conditional check should be `'s'` and not `"s"`. Something between single quotes is a character. Something between double quotes is a string.
4. There should be no semicolon at the end of the if check. Remove it.

- Also change `int d` to `char d`

Comment: To expand on this: The `=` instead of `==` means asker is performing an assignment and checking if the result evaluates to `false` instead of performing a comparison. The double-quotes around `"s"` instead of single-quotes make it a C-style string literal, not a character literal. And the `;` after the `if` statement meant that when the `if` evaluates to `true`, nothing happens; the block below it would execute normally, and the `else` block way below is malformed.

Comment: [Since this is C++, rvalues and lvalues are only the start of the fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).

Comment: And in fact note that `int d` isn't what asker would want to use if you're trying to read a character in anyway, so earlier in the program it should be `char d` (or, preferably, a more descriptive variable name entirely).

Comment: @NathanPierson - no. `int` is the right type to use to input a char - because EOF (-1) is int - https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html

Comment: @user93353 This is a C++ question. Your text there is about using `getchar` in C, not `std::istream`s in C++.

Comment: @NathanPierson true. Updated the answer.